# Windows route with virtualbox network configuation

Tags: virtualbox

There are two network cards in my workstation. One for our local network and one for internet access.

The local network card has static ip address `192.168.1.10` with gateway of `192.168.1.1`.

The internet network card has static ip `192.168.155.*` with gateway of `192.168.155.1`.

Now I use the route to make the pc access local network and internte at the sametime.

```
route ADD     0.0.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0  192.168.155.1 # default use the internet network card 
route ADD 192.168.1.0 MASK 255.255.255.0  192.168.1.1   # for local network
```

It worked.

However I have VirtualBox installed, and there is  a guest vm with `bridge network` with static ip `192.168.1.11`. I can not access that after I set the route.

Is it possbile to make the host and guest can access each other, also make the guest vm can access both local and internet?

---

update:

Before I set the route, my virtualbox guest vm works as expected, so  I think there is not problem with the configuration with the vbox.

Comment: You have a typo in your first line. Should be 192.168.1.1 for the gateway. At least according to your route. Does the gateway know about the 1.11 address? In that case it shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. The `1.11` is a virtualbox guest, I am not sure if the gateway can identify that.

Comment: If it does it should work. Your traffic would get from your workstation to the gateway and back to your workstation. Make sure the VM has a route/configuration that sets up the gateway. If you're running it in bridged mode there are two devices next to each other, in a way. An other option might be to setup a route with a metric for the `1.11` address that is lower than the general `1.0` route.

Comment: See my update. Also I have tried the metric, it does not work.

Comment: Your route tells your computer to redirect any traffic it has for 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.1.1. What did you try for the metric and which route did you add for it? What doesn't work if you don't setup those routes?